# Auto mount a disk drive in ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Bookmark directory not found)

Tags: 14.04, mount, directory, automount, filemanager

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I start my pc and click on any bookmark from the file manager it shows this error:

```
Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.
Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/media/angel/DOC/edu': No such file or directory
```

But when I open DOC drive and again clink on the same bookmark it works properly. Can anybody tell me why is this happening and how to solve this issue?

Edit: Output of `lsblk` is following: (ubuntu is installed in `sda5`)

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  91.3G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  24.1G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  93.2G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  93.2G  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0  89.3G  0 part 
├─sdb7   8:23   0  93.2G  0 part 
├─sdb8   8:24   0  93.2G  0 part 
└─sdb9   8:25   0   3.8G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

After opening the disk drive the output of `lsblk` is bellow:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  91.3G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  24.1G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  93.2G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  93.2G  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0  89.3G  0 part /media/angel/DOC
├─sdb7   8:23   0  93.2G  0 part 
├─sdb8   8:24   0  93.2G  0 part 
└─sdb9   8:25   0   3.8G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The output of `sudo blkid` gives the following information about `sdb6`:

```
/dev/sdb6: LABEL="DOC" UUID="04280A22280A12FA" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the output of `lsblk`, before and after the link starts working, it appears that your partition is not mounted automatically.

Since it is an NTFS partition (looking at the output of `sudo blkid`), you can make your partition automount by adding the following line to your `fstab` file:

```
/dev/sdb6 /media/angel/DOC ntfs auto
```

- If it does not exist already, create the directory to mount into:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /media/angel/DOC
  ```
- Open the `fstab` file:

  ```
  gksu gedit /etc/fstab
  ```

  (you might have to install gksu first)

  and add the line:

  ```
  /dev/sdb6 /media/angel/DOC ntfs auto
  ```

  at the end of the file, save the changes.
- Test your new entry by the command:

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem as @mostafiz . what is angel? while making a new directory i am getting this error `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/angel/DOC’: No such file or directory`  . If we have more than one ntfs drive do we have to add those to the fstab.. eg */dev/sdb6 /media/angel/DOC ntfs auto* ; */dev/sdb5 /media/angel/DOC ntfs auto* etc

Comment: @Eka You will probably not have the directory `/media/angel/`, so you cannot create the directory `/Doc` inside it :). You'd probably have enough to use `/media/<mountpoint_name>` (without the subdirectory `/angel/Doc`, I assume angel is his name).  For every partition, indeed you need to have a separate line in the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: @Eka not needed in this case, but if you need to create a new directory inside another directory that not yet exists (create directories recursively), you need to use the `-p`option. e.g. to create directorie(s) `/media/monkey/eats/banana` inside an empty folder `/media`: `sudo mkdir -p /media/monkey/eats/banana`.

Comment: So i have tried your method and its able to mount drives but some how i cant open bookmarked folder (laucher file manager icon) without manually mounting the drives by clicking on it.

Comment: Could you test restarting and run `lsblk` to see if the drive is mounted? If not can you run `sudo mount -a` to see what is wrong? I am pretty sure the drive is not mounted automatically, it will show nevertheless in the devices section when it is in `/etc/fstab`  :)

Comment: k i will try that and let you know

Comment: sorry for the late reply but was working in ubuntu so had to wait to complete my work. I have restarted my system and a `lsblk` check showed that the disk is mounted after a fresh restart  and `sudo mount -a` didnt showed any results

Comment: @Eka You might have to recreate the bookmarks. Probably its path has changed.

Comment: Hey thanks..you are correct it was due to the change in path. I once again made a new bookmark of the folder and after restart its working perfectly. Once more thanks for your help

Comment: @Eka let's say I have a bookmark to a folder on a mounted volume `/media/mountfolder/path/to/folder`. The mountpoint is `/media/mountfolder/`. Now when you add it to your `/etc/fstab` file, this mountpoint will be different although the *foldername* is the same. The full path to the folder will nevertheless be different. What you probably need to do is remove the bookmarks in question and recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

I had to struggle with the same problem. It was due to an missing entry in the fstab file.

Lets say the bookmark is in folder **/dev/sda1/bookmark**. Then the bookmark only worked when I first opened the folder **/dev/sda1** with the Explorer Window.

After a restart the command `lsblk -f` showed that **/dev/sda1** was not mounted, without mountpoint.

Accessing **/dev/sda1** in the Explorer Window and retype the command `lsblk -f` it appeared with its mountpoint on **/media/user/sda1**.

After some time I percepted that an entry in the fstab file was missing.

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

I put the following line into fstab file:

```
/dev/sda1   /media/user/sda1  ntfs  rw,user,auto    0   2
```

I used the mountpoint which was defined by the system after accessing **/dev/sda1** manually.

Finally it worked after a restart.

I hope it will help for other cases as well.

Comment: `/dev/sda1` is a device, not a directory, so part of this answer is unclear.