# Desktop shortcuts getting corrupted in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: filesystem

If I create a desktop shortcut in Ubuntu, for my folder(s) off my local drive, and when I login the next time, **the shortcut link will be EXPIRED!** If I try clicking that link, I get a message that the source file doesn't exist anymore even though it does.

I'm running Ubuntu alongside with Windows 7.
Have I committed any mistakes while installing?
Or I'm ready to install both of these OS's from the start if that could help solve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto mount a disk drive in ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Bookmark directory not found)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525498/auto-mount-a-disk-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-bookmark-directory-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it myself, here is the way:

1. Go to search and type "disks"
2. open the app named disks
3. a window will open and it will show you your partitions
4. now browse the partition where your soured file lies (file or folder you wish to create the shortcut)
5. select that partition and click settings
6. click "edit mount options"
7. in the "mount options"window switch off the automatic mount options switch
8. check "mount at startup" and "show in user interface"
9. click ok
10. delete all the shortcuts and create them new
11. from now even if you restart your pc the shortcuts will remain