# Ubuntu Desktop shortcuts 'No longer exists'

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 7 dual-boot.

If I try creating a shortcut of a folder from my local drive, say "E:" and send it to ubuntu desktop, the next time I log in to Ubuntu, the folder will be grayed-out and when I try double-clicking it, I get a message

**"The link to "Camera" is broken.Move it to trash?**

The link cannot be used because it's target "media/myself/pics/camera" doesn't exist.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto mount a disk drive in ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Bookmark directory not found)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525498/auto-mount-a-disk-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-bookmark-directory-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you create shortcuts to ntfs partitions, which are not permanently mounted. You probably click on a Windows partition in file manager, and it is mounted. When you boot next time, you get this error message. To avoid it you can edit /etc/fstab to mount Windows partitions at start automatically.

[This will help to underatand it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

[This is another manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)

Comment: I'm totally a newbie to Ubuntu, the links provided by you is really helpful but as I'm new to this environment, could you please tell me how to mount them on start-up and to not see that error every time I log in? In the meantime, I'll be checking out the links that you've given.

Comment: You need to edit file /etc/fstab as directed in given links.

Comment: In one of the steps explained, it says: Now open /etc/fstab in a text editor with root privileges. In Ubuntu:

gksudo gedit /etc/fstab                                    How to open text editor with root privileges?

Comment: It says how to do it. By running "gksudo gedit /etc/fstab".