# NTFS drive does not automounts

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, automount

I have an NTFS drive that is set to automount at startup but for some reason it doesn't. (There is another drive with same properties that does.)

Any ideas why?

[image]

Comment: could you read your `fstab` file (run `cat /etc/fstab`) and add the line in `fstab` that *should* take care of the automount?

Comment: @JacobVlijm There is only the Ubuntu drive there

Comment: I see. I really don't like GUI tools to make partitions automount; it usually makes more complicated, while it is really easy to do it manually, like (e.g.) described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/525516/72216 . You can also use the `uuid` to avoid *any* possibility to mix up; run `sudo blkid` to find out the `uuid`. The line in `fstab` should then look like:  `UUID=0A444ED409660B91 /media/intern_1 ntfs auto` (from my `fstab`)

Comment: @JacobVlijm this should be an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### GUI tools to make partitions automount

From your comment, I understand the GUI tool did not add anything to your `fstab` file. In general, I am not very fond of GUI tools to edit `fstab`; many times unnecessary options are added or errors occur.

#### Making an ntfs partition automount, using the uuid

Since making an `ntfs` partition automount is relatively simple, I would prefer to do the following:

1. Create a directory to mount the partition into, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/mountpoint_name
   ```
2. Run `sudo blkid`. It will output lines like:

   ```
   /dev/sda5: LABEL="intern_2" UUID="2899FAA548C61099" TYPE="ntfs"
   ```

   The `uuid` you are looking for is `2899FAA548C61099` in the example above (If that would be the partition you'd like to automount)
3. Open your fstab file:

   ```
   sudo -i gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
4. Add a line to the file, looking like (an entry from my `fstab file as an example`):

   ```
   UUID=0A444ED409660B91 /media/intern_1 ntfs auto
   ```

   (Replace `/media/intern_1` by the mount point you created in `[1]`)

Test the mount by running `sudo mount -a`. The drive should mount, and will automount & show up in "devices" from then on:

[image]

#### Note

In most cases, instead of using the `uuid`, you can simply use the partition's mention (which is also in the output of `sudo blkid), e.g.

```
/dev/sda5 /media/intern_1 ntfs auto
```

Comment: small question: It mounts the drive as root, so any operation requires `sudo`, how do I mount it as my user?

Comment: NTFS drives mounted like this should not require any privileges.  Is there something not working as it should? NTFS even does not support permissions like `ext4`, and the `mount` command requires `sudo` anyway.

Comment: It disabled my shares, and when I try to share folders again it says I don't have permissions. Same with unmounting. Before I could unmount/share from nautilus, with my user, without any problem

Comment: You mean you use the ntfs as a share, to be accessed from other computers?