# Symlinks to Windows folder breaking

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, symbolic-link

I've got a folder of my work on my Windows partition, which I still use from Windows sometimes, so I can't just move it to my Linux partition. So I've made a symlink (both with ln -s and by right clicking on the folder) which I keep in my Linux documents folder, but whenever I turn my computer off and on again, the link breaks. Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening?

EDIT: I have found a workaround, which is simply clicking into the Windows_OS directory before I go and try and access the symlinks mounts the C: drive and fixes the links, but I'd still appreciate it if anyone knows a way to either automate this or stop them breaking in the first place.

Comment: "turn my computer off and on again"? It's a known problem with NTFS, the Windows file system - if you do not shutdown Windows politely, Windows will leave the NTFS partition in an inconsistent state, and Linux cannot mount it. Boot WIndows, and shut it down properly (Click "Start" or whatever).

Comment: you might be able to fix it by editing /etc/fstab to mount the partition at boot. what do you see if you type `grep ntfs /etc/fstab`?

Comment: @waltinator I booted to Windows (10), and shut it down via the start menu, booted to Ubuntu and it wouldn't even let me access the C: drive. So I went back into Windows and shut it down with shutdown /s, as I think the start menu uses the /hybrid command, which prepares it for fast startup. When I then booted to Ubuntu, the symlinks worked, but when I restarted Ubuntu, just from the top right menu shutdown->restart, then links are broken again.

Comment: @Zanna It doesn't come up with anything. It just brings up a new line with the default text in to allow me to type another command into the terminal.

Comment: I guess you're left with reading `dmesg -Tx | less`, and looking at `/var/log/kern.log` to see if your Windows partition is mentioned, and what it says.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto mount a disk drive in ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Bookmark directory not found)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525498/auto-mount-a-disk-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-bookmark-directory-not-found)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an entry to your `fstab` so the partition is mounted with the right permissions at boot

You can read some background info on `fstab` [here in Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

You will want to mount the drive with read write permission, so you need the filesystem label to be `ntfs-3g`. First check that you have the package:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

probably it will say you already have the latest version, which is cool.

Next, choose a mount point for your partition. You probably know where it is normally mounted when you open it from your Ubuntu partition. You can either use that mount point, or make a new one. You can call it anything but it should be in `/media`.

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
```

Now please backup your `fstab`:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab-backup
```

To undo the changes any time `sudo mv /etc/fstab-backup /etc/fstab`

You need the UUID of your windows partition so run

```
sudo blkid
```

You will see all your partitions with `UUID="VeryLongString-OfLetters&Numbers"` You can identify the windows partition by its filesystem tag `TYPE="ntfs"`. Copy the UUID of the partition. Now you are ready to make your new entry in fstab so

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

at the end of the file, make a new line with UUID, then the mountpoint you chose, then filesystem type, then options, then two separated zeroes, like this

```
UUID=that-long-string-you-copied /media/windows   ntfs-3g    auto,user,rw   0   0
```

the options mean it will mount automatically at boot, and be read & writable by you (not just root) the two zeros are just null options (see the help page linked above). You might want to add a comment (starting the line with #) on the line above for future reference like:

```
# To make my symlinks persistent
```

Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd>) and exit, then reboot. If you did everything right, you will find your partition at the mountpoint you selected. Make your symlinks again and now they will survive power cycles.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it appears to be working now. For the record, I had to change ntfs-g3 to just ntfs in /etc/fstab otherwise I got an error during booting.

Comment: That's good that it works! What error did you get with ntfs-3g?

Comment: On boot, it said An error occurred while trying to mount /media/dominic/Windows8_OS, if I try to mount from the terminal, it said mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-g3', which stems from a typo in your example entry to fstab where you put ntfs-g3, rather than ntfs-3g. Changing it to 3g makes it mount fine.

Comment: oops! that was a really bad typo, sorry! fixed it.